# A better way to bind all the functions of a JS constructor?

Tags: javascript, binding, ecmascript-5, flux

I am working with a custom implementation of the Flux Design Pattern and my Store's have a lot of functions which get registered on the global dispatcher.  As a result I am having to bind all these functions to keep the reference to "this".

The problem is that the code is very verbose.  I am having to write the same function name three times for each function.  Below is an example of what I am talking about.  I have to write this.selectClassList three times.  Once for defining the function,  then two more times to bind it properly.

```
      this.selectClassList = function(){
        this.forumSelected = false;
        this.classListSelected = true;
        this.isDocsTabSelected = false;
        this.pub();
      }
      this.selectClassList = this.selectClassList.bind(this)
      this.classSelectId = this.dis.reg('showClassList', this.selectClassList);
```

This would be okay if I was only binding one or two functions from the stores.  But there are dozens of functions like this.

Is there some way to bind ALL the functions to the current context that would save the hassle of writing the same function name three times?

I've tried something like Object.keys(obj) but that does not work on constructor functions.

Note: my solution has to be ES5, no arrow functions.

Comment: `this.selectClassList = (function() { ... }).bind(this)` or just use an arrow function

Comment: Thanks man,  ye I can't use arrow functions cause this is for production.  (es6 features are not supported by a lot of browsers still )